# mMenuDrawer returns null in logcat

Tags: java, android

I have been following the github tutorial on Menu drawers with simonvt library. I have tried to implement this with my project for 2 days but I can't figure out the problem. I tried to debug the app and I get an exception error at Main activity. on-site with mMenuDrawer highlighted with the value of null.

Please can someone help me understand the problem, thanks.

```
package     net.simonvt.menudrawer.samples;

import net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer;
import net.simonvt.menudrawer.Position;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RightMenuSample extends   Activity {

    private static final String STATE_ACTIVE_POSITION = "net.simonvt.menudrawer.samples.RightMenuSample.activePosition";
    private static final String STATE_CONTENT_TEXT = "net.simonvt.menudrawer.samples.RightMenuSample.contentText";

    private static final int MENU_OVERFLOW = 1;

private MenuDrawer mMenuDrawer;

private MenuAdapter mAdapter;
private ListView mList;

private int mActivePosition = -1;
private String mContentText;
private TextView mContentTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle inState) {
super.onCreate(inState);

if (inState != null) {
mActivePosition =  inState.getInt(STATE_ACTIVE_POSITION);
mContentText = inState.getString(STATE_CONTENT_TEXT);
    }

mMenuDrawer = MenuDrawer.attach(this, MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_CONTENT, Position.RIGHT);
         mMenuDrawer.setContentView(R.layout.activity_rightmenu);

List<Object> items = new ArrayList<Object>();
items.add(new Item("Item 1",  R.drawable.ic_action_refresh_dark));
items.add(new Item("Item 2", R.drawable.ic_action_select_all_dark));
items.add(new Category("Cat 1"));
items.add(new Item("Item 3", R.drawable.ic_action_refresh_dark));
items.add(new Item("Item 4", R.drawable.ic_action_select_all_dark));
items.add(new Category("Cat 2"));
items.add(new Item("Item 5", R.drawable.ic_action_refresh_dark));
items.add(new Item("Item 6", R.drawable.ic_action_select_all_dark));

// A custom ListView is needed so the drawer can be notified when it's scrolled. This is to update the position
// of the arrow indicator.
mList = new ListView(this);
mAdapter = new MenuAdapter(items);
mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);mList.setOnItemClickListener(mItemClickListener);

mMenuDrawer.setMenuView(mList);

mContentTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contentText);
    mContentTextView.setText(mContentText);
}

private
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
mItemClickListener = new
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mActivePosition = position;

mMenuDrawer.setActiveView(view, position);
mContentTextView.setText(((TextView) view).getText());
mMenuDrawer.closeMenu();
}
};

@Override
protected void
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVE_POSITION, mActivePosition);
    outState.putString(STATE_CONTENT_TEXT, mContentText);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem overflowItem = menu.add(0, MENU_OVERFLOW, 0, null);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        overflowItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    }
    overflowItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_OVERFLOW:
            mMenuDrawer.toggleMenu();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    final int drawerState = mMenuDrawer.getDrawerState();
    if (drawerState == MenuDrawer.STATE_OPEN || drawerState == MenuDrawer.STATE_OPENING) {
        mMenuDrawer.closeMenu();
        return;
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}

private static class Item {

    String mTitle;
    int mIconRes;

    Item(String title, int iconRes) {
        mTitle = title;
        mIconRes = iconRes;
    }
}

private static class Category {

    String mTitle;

    Category(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }
}

private class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Object> mItems;

    MenuAdapter(List<Object> items) {
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return getItem(position) instanceof Item ? 0 : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return getItem(position) instanceof Item;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        Object item = getItem(position);

        if (item instanceof Category) {
            if (v == null) {
                v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_row_category, parent, false);
            }

            ((TextView) v).setText(((Category) item).mTitle);

        } else {
            if (v == null) {
                v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_row_item, parent, false);
            }

            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setText(((Item) item).mTitle);
            tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(((Item) item).mIconRes, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        v.setTag(R.id.mdActiveViewPosition, position);

        if (position == mActivePosition) {
            mMenuDrawer.setActiveView(v, position);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

}

This is my logcat

```
10-30 11:32:04.260: W/dalvikvm(21881): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lnet/simonvt/menudrawer/MenuDrawer;)
10-30 11:32:04.265: I/dalvikvm(21881): Could not find method net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer.getDrawerState, referenced from method com.example.grossbeatwindow.MainActivity.onBackPressed
10-30 11:32:04.265: W/dalvikvm(21881): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4305: Lnet/simonvt/menudrawer/MenuDrawer;.getDrawerState ()I
10-30 11:32:04.265: D/dalvikvm(21881): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-30 11:32:04.265: W/dalvikvm(21881): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1103 (RIGHT) in Lnet/simonvt/menudrawer/Position;
10-30 11:32:04.265: D/dalvikvm(21881): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x001b
10-30 11:32:04.265: I/dalvikvm(21881): Could not find method net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer.toggleMenu, referenced from method com.example.grossbeatwindow.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected
10-30 11:32:04.265: W/dalvikvm(21881): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4309: Lnet/simonvt/menudrawer/MenuDrawer;.toggleMenu ()V
10-30 11:32:04.265: D/dalvikvm(21881): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
10-30 11:32:04.265: W/dalvikvm(21881): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lnet/simonvt/menudrawer/MenuDrawer;)
10-30 11:32:04.265: I/dalvikvm(21881): Could not find method net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer.setActiveView, referenced from method com.example.grossbeatwindow.MainActivity$1.onItemClick
10-30 11:32:04.265: W/dalvikvm(21881): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4306: Lnet/simonvt/menudrawer/MenuDrawer;.setActiveView (Landroid/view/View;I)V
10-30 11:32:04.265: D/dalvikvm(21881): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
10-30 11:32:04.280: D/AndroidRuntime(21881): Shutting down VM
10-30 11:32:04.280: W/dalvikvm(21881): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e0b700)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.simonvt.menudrawer.Position
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at com.example.grossbeatwindow.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
10-30 11:32:04.285: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I can't even find `mDrawer` on your code...

Comment: I initialized mMenuDrawer before onCreate or is their something am doing wrong?

Comment: `Mainactivity.onCreate with mDrawer highlighted`. Where is `mDrawer`? Did you mean `mMenuDrawer`?

Comment: Sorry for my typo I mean mMenuDrawer.

Comment: Is there a reason you not using a navigation drawer?

Comment: Yes I really love the features of this library. Expecially the MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_CONTENT and MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_WINDOW feature which drags the action bar as well. Navigation drawer from android doc doesn't support this.

Comment: Please guys Any help is appreciated. This is the lib I used http://simonvt.github.io/android-menudrawer/

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed this. The problem was from my lib referencing. I had to add my lib class folder from java build bath > libraries > add class folder. And selected menudrawer folder inside simonvt. Then went to order and export and selected the folder. Thanks guys.